# Nest can't resolve dependencies of the BookingService

Tags: nestjs

I checked a lot of answers, but still got this error. I hope you will help me to see what i missed

> Error: Nest can't resolve dependencies of the BookingService
> (BookingRepository, ?, UserRepository). Please make sure that the
> argument TableRepository at index [1] is available in the
> BookingModule context. Potential solutions:
>
> - If TableRepository is a provider, is it part of the current BookingModule?
> - If TableRepository is exported from a separate @Module, is that module imported within BookingModule?   @Module({
>   imports: [ /* the Module containing TableRepository */ ]   })

my **booking.service.ts**:

```
@Injectable()
export class BookingService {
    constructor(
        @InjectRepository(Booking)
        private readonly repository: Repository<Booking>,
        @InjectRepository(Table)
        private readonly tableRepository: Repository<Table>,
        @InjectRepository(User)
        private readonly userRepository: Repository<User>
    ) {}
  }
```

my **app.module.ts**:

```
@Module({
      imports: [
        TypeOrmModule.forRoot({ autoLoadEntities: true }),
        TableModule,
        RestaurantModule,
        UserModule,
        BookingModule
      ],
      controllers: [AppController],
      providers: [AppService],
      exports: [TypeOrmModule]
    })
    export class AppModule {}
```

my **booking.module.ts**:

```
@Module({
    imports: [TypeOrmModule.forFeature([Booking]), TableModule],
    controllers: [BookingController],
    providers: [BookingService]
})
export class BookingModule {}
```

my **table.module.ts**:

```
@Module({
    imports: [TypeOrmModule.forFeature([Table])],
    controllers: [TableController],
    providers: [TableService],
    exports: [TableService]
})
export class TableModule {}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're wanting to inject the `TableRepository`, you should either add `TypeOrmModule.forFeature([Table])` to the `BookingModule`, or you should add `TypeOrmModule` to the `exports` of `TableModule`. The latter will only create one instance of the `TableRepository`, so that would be my suggestion, but both will work in the end.

Comment: I guess it was because service, but after adding  `TypeOrmModule` to the `exports` of `TableModule` it runs on. Thank you so much <3<3<3